# Allocate number of items in one table to available space in another

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016

i have two tables:

```
#shelves(id INT, shelve_size INT);
id shelve_size
1   5
2   19
3   64
4   9

#palettes(id INT, number_of_items INT)
id number_of_items
1   3
2   9
3   32
```

i need a query that shows something like this, without using a while loop:

```
id shelve_size number_of_items used available
1  5           3               3    2
1  5           9               2    0
2  19          9               7    12
2  19          32              12   0 
3  64          32              20   44      
4  9           0               0    9 <- not necesary row
```

It unpacks the palettes in Id order and stores them on shelves in id order. If a shelf is not full after unpacking one palette the next one uses any remaining capacity.

The first shelve size has capacity 5 so gets the 3 items from the 1st pallet and 2 from the second one. That leaves 7 items of pallet 2 that are stored on shelf 2. After which shelf 2 has space for 20 items. And so on.

Comment: This doesn't make any sense...what is the relationship between one table and the other...can you elaborate a little more?

Comment: Not only it doesn't make sense, this is not a "do work for me for free" site. Show the code that you have tried.

Comment: There is no relationship between the tables to join them.

Comment: Makes sense to me. The first shelve size has capacity 5 so gets the 3 from the  1st  row of the second table and 2 from the second row. That leaves the first shelf full and 7 of the second item still to allocate.

Comment: Are LEAD and LAG analytic functions supported in tsql?

Comment: @TedFilippidis - In SQL Server 2012 or later - arturogranillo what version are you on?

Comment: Do the shelves need to be filled in at any particular order?

Comment: @MartinSmith - Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (SP1)(X64)

Comment: @TedFilippidis - yes, id order.

Comment: OK maybe a combination of SUM OVER PARTITION and LAG can be used to achieve this, but probably will take me a long time to figure out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's start with a simple example. There are 4 shelves S1, S2, S3, S4 - all with room for 5 items.

And three pallets P1 (3 units), P2 (13 units), and P3 (3 units).

It is easy to visualise that the result at the end will be the shelves laid out as follows.

```
+----+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
|    | Slot 1 | Slot 2 | Slot 3 | Slot 4 | Slot 5 |
+----+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
| S1 | P1     | P1     | P1     | P2     | P2     |
| S2 | P2     | P2     | P2     | P2     | P2     |
| S3 | P2     | P2     | P2     | P2     | P2     |
| S4 | P2     | P3     | P3     | P3     |        |
+----+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
```

To do this in SQL I added a couple of running total columns to both tables.

### Shelf

```
+----------+------+---------------------+---------------------+
| shelf_id | size | cume size exclusive | cume size inclusive |
+----------+------+---------------------+---------------------+
| S1       |    5 |                   0 |                   5 |
| S2       |    5 |                   5 |                  10 |
| S3       |    5 |                  10 |                  15 |
| S4       |    5 |                  15 |                  20 |
+----------+------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

### Pallet

```
+------------+------------+---------------------------+---------------------------+
| pallet_id  | item count | cume item count exclusive | cume item count inclusive |
+------------+------------+---------------------------+---------------------------+
| P1         |          3 |                         0 |                         3 |
| P2         |         13 |                         3 |                        16 |
| P3         |          3 |                        16 |                        19 |
+------------+------------+---------------------------+---------------------------+
```

A pallet will go (at least partially) on a shelf if

- the shelf has space for it - i.e the capacity of the shelf (and all previous shelves) is greater than the space already used by all previous palettes. `cume size inclusive > cume item count exclusive`
- the pallet has not already been entirely unpacked. - i.e. the capacity of all previous shelves is less than the space required to unpack all pallets including the current one. `cume size exclusive < cume item count inclusive`

The `available` can be easily calculated by looking to see if the shelf is full after the pallet is entirely unpacked and returning 0 if so or `cume_size_inclusive - cume_item_count_inclusive` otherwise.

The `used` is calculated by looking at the pallet item count and deducting items stored on previous or on subsequent shelves.

This should do it. [Demo](http://rextester.com/XIFOT38623)

```
WITH S
     AS (SELECT *,
                SUM(size) OVER (ORDER BY shelf_id ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) - size AS cume_shelf_capacity_exclusive,
                SUM(size) OVER (ORDER BY shelf_id ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING)        AS cume_shelf_capacity_inclusive
         FROM   #shelves),
     P
     AS (SELECT *,
                SUM(item_count) OVER (ORDER BY pallet_id ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) - item_count AS cume_items_exclusive,
                SUM(item_count) OVER (ORDER BY pallet_id ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING)              AS cume_items_inclusive
         FROM   #palettes)
SELECT S.shelf_id,
       S.size,
       number_of_items = ISNULL(P.item_count, 0),
       used = ISNULL(item_count, 0) - IIF(cume_items_inclusive > cume_shelf_capacity_inclusive, cume_items_inclusive - cume_shelf_capacity_inclusive, 0) --overspill to next shelves
            - IIF(cume_shelf_capacity_exclusive > cume_items_exclusive, cume_shelf_capacity_exclusive - cume_items_exclusive, 0), --stocked on previous shelves
       available = IIF(cume_shelf_capacity_inclusive < cume_items_inclusive, 0, ISNULL(cume_shelf_capacity_inclusive - cume_items_inclusive, S.size))
FROM   S
       LEFT JOIN P
         ON S.cume_shelf_capacity_inclusive > P.cume_items_exclusive
            AND S.cume_shelf_capacity_exclusive < P.cume_items_inclusive
ORDER BY shelf_id, 
         pallet_id;
```

Comment: Wow! Kudos for going through with trying it out

Comment: @TedFilippidis - personally I found it an interesting question!